# Copying Multiple Cells based on a criteria and printing all of them onto one cell

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I would like to use vba to copy multiple cells based on a criteria and paste all of the information onto one cell in another worksheet. I am looking to paste them just in one cell.

What I would like to code to do is that If the value in column D is "red", I would like to copy the info from column A and B from that specific row where the value in D is "red", and paste the entire information onto only one cell as combined information. I would also want a loop that would do that for each row and again would paste that information onto just once cell without deleting the previously pasted information from the previous row where column D was still "red".

I know that I would have to use a loop that would check each row or each cell in D and then an If statement which would check whether it says Red and then copy the offset from column D but I am not sure how to paste all of that Information onto one cell only. I have tried using other sources of information and I am bit stuck. It might be trivial but I am relatively new to vba.

These are how the 4 columns look like.

```
1.a A3-1B   R   red

2.c A8-2G   R   red

3.f B2-2E   B   blue

4.b A4-B8   B   blue

5.a A7-B10  R   red

6.c A4-C7   G   green

7.b D9-VB   Y   yellow
```

at the end I would like the filtered information in only One cell to look like this:

```
a A3-1B

c A8-2G

a A7-B10
```

I have included just a simple code which I know is nowhere near what I would need. As it only copies the information from B and how this loop is formed it will give me only the information from the last row.

```
Sub sort2()

    Dim SingleCell As Range
    Dim ListOfCells As Range

    Set ListOfCells = Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))

    For Each SingleCell In ListOfCells

        If SingleCell.Value = "red" Then

            SingleCell.Offset(0, 2).Copy

        End If

        Worksheet.Add
        Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    Next SingleCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution based on what I understood. Hopefully it provides extra strategies for you that you can use in other VBA going forward.

```
Sub DoStuff()

    '' Set Source and Target Sheets
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Set srcSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source") '' Source Data store on sheet called Source

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Result") '' Sheet where I want to store results

    Dim SingleCell As Range
    Dim ListOfCells As Range

    Set ListOfCells = srcSheet.Range("D2", srcSheet.Range("D2").End(xlDown))

    Dim foundColor As Range
    Dim nextAvailableCell As Range

    For Each SingleCell In ListOfCells

        'If SingleCell.Value = "red" Then
        '    SingleCell.Offset(0, 2).Copy
        'End If

        'Worksheet.Add
        'Range("A1").PasteSpecial

        '' Find where the current color is on targetSheet in column A
        '' Find result must be a whole cell match ie red doesn't match red-orange
        Set foundColor = targetSheet.Range("A:A").Find(what:=SingleCell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

        '' If it found a cell with that color append it to the existing text
        If Not foundColor Is Nothing Then
            '' the new value is the current value PLUS a new line PLUS the appending text
            '' using .Value method skips the clipboard and is much faster than copy/paste
            foundColor.Offset(0, 1).Value = foundColor.Offset(0, 1).Value & _
                                            vbCrLf & _
                                            SingleCell.Offset(0, -3).Value & " " & _
                                            SingleCell.Offset(0, -2).Value

        '' Otherwise create a new "Entry"
        Else
            '' Get the first available (blank) row
            '' ASSUMING NO HEADERS NEEDED ON RESULT SHEET
            '========================
            If targetSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
                Set nextAvailableCell = targetSheet.Cells(1, 1)
            Else
                Set nextAvailableCell = targetSheet.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
            '========================

            '' Copy the Info
            nextAvailableCell.Value = SingleCell.Value
            nextAvailableCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = SingleCell.Offset(0, -3).Value & " " & _
                                                   SingleCell.Offset(0, -2).Value

        End If

    Next SingleCell


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will give it a try tomorrow and see how it works. Again thank you in advance for the help , I really appreaciate it

Comment: It will probably need some changes specific to where you are copying data. But the core of it should all be there.

Comment: absolutely brilliant i changed a few bits but the code works even better than I wanted it to do. Extremely grateful for the help